# Azure oidc access token formats

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect

We're using azure and openid connect to provide an SSO for our users,and I've noticed that access tokens are produced in 2 different formats, 99% of the time, we're getting a regular JWT, starting with eyJ and dot (.) seperated. But the remaining 1% we get access tokens like this EwAoA8l6BAAU 
All documentation I've found online says those are base 64 encoded jwt's but I've yet to find a base 64 decoder that will produce anything remotely usable from them.

I know that we're supposed to consider access tokens as opaque, but the reason I even discovered this is that those 1% of access token also seems to behave differently, eg. the users they return from lookups in the graph-api /me endpoint, don't match what was in the corresponding id-token.

So, does anybody know the reason for the EwAoA8l6BAAU formatted access tokens, and how to decode them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokens that begin with `EwBQA8l6BAAU` are consumer Microsoft Accounts (aka `outlook.com`, `XBox Live`, etc.).

They are encrypted and I'm not aware of a tool capable of fully decoding them.

Comment: One aside, if you require the `openid` scope it will provide you an `id_token` which _is_ a normal JWT token.

Comment: I think there is no way we can get the access token. Because the question to that is what are you going to use it for?